# Can anyone explain how to use mtp2 font on Overleaf?

Tags: fonts, overleaf, installing-fonts, mathtime

I have been using Overleaf my entire academic career. Recently I have been asked to use mpt2 font. I have the license for it, but I am not sure how to install it for use on Overleaf.

Can anyone shed some light or direct me to a tutorial explaining how to do this? I have read the article in the LaTeX manual,

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F#If_you.27re_using_pdfLaTeX_or_LaTeX

But I am not sure if the commands in the 'latexmkrc' file need to be changed in any way, or if the compressed .zip file of the font needs to be unzipped in Overleaf? I am not sure if you can unzip within Overleaf?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: you tagged this as [tag:fontspec] are you usung luatex or xetex? the mathtime fonts are 8bit fonts usually used with pdftex?

Comment: Yes, I'm using pdfLaTeX. I didn't realise fontspec was specific to other compilers. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Overleaf manual has detailed instructions:  [https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I'd_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F)

Comment: Boris, I tried to follow these instructions but nothing seems to be working. Am I supposed to upload the .zip file of mtp2, or unzip this file and upload individual files? I can't see any files of the form '.tfm', etc. only '.tpm'. Do you have any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: You need to unzip the file on overleaf.  There should be files like mt2bbdf.tfm   mt2bmff.tfm   mt2bsyas.tfm  mt2hbis.tfm   mt2hsyas.tfm  mt2mct.tfm    mt2syaf.tfm
mt2bbds.tfm   mt2bmfs.tfm   mt2bsyat.tfm  mt2hbit.tfm   mt2hsyat.tfm  mt2mff.tfm    mt2syas.tfm
mt2bbdt.tfm etc