# MathTimes Professional 2 fonts in Overleaf

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

I am a beginner in using overleaf to yield latex file. I found from the sample online that the mtpro2 package provides really good math fonts for typsetting. I downloaded the mtpro2 lite zip.file and tried to make it work in the overleaf. However, I cannot find more information about how to enable mtpro2 work in overleaf besides this post [Can anyone explain how to use mtp2 font on Overleaf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614788/can-anyone-explain-how-to-use-mtp2-font-on-overleaf) (which is also vague and maybe unsolved...). I am sorry but I am really new to handle this and could anyone give me some help?

Comment: as the answer there says unzip the file locally then upload the individual files to overleaf